# to show image and title from arrayList of objects, in grids

Tags: android, object

I want to get the image and text from given objects, without using an adapter.
Is it possible to fetch so that I can show 3 images with title in every row?

```
    ItemData itemsData[] = {new ItemData("Kerala", "wayanadu", "silent valley", R.drawable.kerala),
             new ItemData("Goa", "Palolem", "Palolem beach", R.drawable.g),
             new ItemData("New Delhi", "Delhi", "India gate", R.drawable.gate),
             new ItemData("Punjab", "Amritsar", " Golden Temple", R.drawable.go),
             new ItemData("Karnataka ", "Mysuru", "mysore palace", R.drawable.mysuru),
             new ItemData("Madhya Pradesh", "Kanha", "Kanha NationalPark", R.drawable.k),
             new ItemData("TamilNadu", "Chennai", "Merina beach", R.drawable.merina),
             new ItemData("New Delh", "Mehrauli", "Qutub Minar", R.drawable.q),
             new ItemData("Rajasthan ", "Jaisalmer", "jaisalmer", R.drawable.r)
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html). see [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/linearlayoutmanager-and.html) example for reference